# How to edit a record using Ajax in wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am sorry if this question is already answered. Since i am new to Ajax and i am trying to edit a record of users table of wordpress. I have used for loop to display users and the query is:

```
foreach($user_info as $newu){ ?>
    <tr>                
        <td contenteditable="true" name="userid"><?php echo $newu->id;?></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"><?php echo $newu->user_login;?></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"><?php echo $newu-> user_nicename;?></td>     
        <td contenteditable="true" class="editrow"><?php echo $newu-> user_email;?></td>        
        <td><input type="submit" id='<?php echo $newu->id; ?>' class="todelete" name="delete" value='Delete' /></td>        
        <td><input type="submit" id='<?php echo $newu->id; ?>' class="toedit" name="edit" value='Edit' /></td>              

    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**and the output is:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1MQA.png)

Delete is working perfectly but it is hard for me to edit. I would appreciate more for simple and straight solution. Thank you

Comment: name attribute is missing for other things than userid, and by the way you can't directly change the username from frontend

Comment: add the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

Name attribute is missing for fields other than `userid`, without name attribute form action wont serialize the data.